# Git resolve conflicts develop and release branch when develop can only be modified through pull requests

Tags: git, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a problem when trying to merge (--no-ff) release/11 branch to dev branch (first a merge (--no-ff) to master branch was already done):

[image]

On release/11 and dev branches the same file was changed so we have conflict on PR:

[image]

But after locally resolving conflicts on dev I cannot push the changes directly to dev as:

[image]

Could anyone help how to deal with this problem?

Comment: yes of course, you need to raise a PR to merge your changes in dev

Comment: but I have to resolve my changes on dev branch locally and cannot "git push" dev to remote dev, that is the problem

Comment: Whoever set up the rules, either did not anticipate this situation, or decided that in this situation, it should be impossible to do what you want to do. You'll have to make a *different branch* in which you resolve the conflict, and merge from *that branch* to `dev` (via PR), not from `release/11`. It is either that, or rescind the rule.

Comment: @torek What I am thinking on is to work as usual, if we have merge conflict on  ```dev``` then change access rights for single user (admin) to be able to push changes from local  ```dev``` with resolved conflicts to remote  ```dev```

Comment: @cincin21: that would work. Or, GitHub themselves already anticipated this situation: they have the concept of admin users who are allowed to push directly, vs non-admin users who must raise pull requests. Put someone into the admin-users direct-push-allowed list, and you don't have to change any access rights.

Comment: @torek We are using BitBucket so no option like this

Comment: @cincin21: Ah, well, that seems terrible. GitHub were able to anticipate this need; the Bitbucket folks surely should have thought of it too. Perhaps you can request it as a feature... :-)

Comment: @cincin21 no one should push changes directly without getting it reviewed that's the reason we need to raise PR to merge our changes.

Comment: @AmitKarnik I understand but how can you resolve conflicts on ```dev``` branch, when even BitBucket propose to resolve them on ```dev``` branch ?

Comment: @cincin21 you can make a branch out of dev brach, fix and raise PR to dev

Comment: @AmitKarnik that could work, but we're building additional PR, still good idea for a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while waiting for any suggestions I've added myself as only user available to push directly on `dev` branch and at present I can resolve conflicts in my IDE and then push them to `dev`.

Maybe someone can think of different approach.